# State change in my component is not reflected in column definition callback functions in Ag-Grid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

In a component that uses Ag-Grid, I have a

```
const [updateData, setUpdateData] = useState({});
```

The `setUpdateData` is also being called from somewhere else to reset `updateData` to `{}`. But that reset is not reflected in this `onCellValueChanged` function, which is plugged into `onCellValueChanged` attribute of `columnDefs`. Why is `updateData` changed in other parts of the code not reflected in `columnDefs`?

```
const onCellValueChanged = ({ column, data: cellData, newValue, node }) => {
    const existingEntry = updateData[cellData.account_id];
    if (existingEntry) {
      updateData[cellData.account_id] = {
        ...existingEntry,
        [column.colId]: Number(newValue),
      };
    } else {
      updateData[cellData.account_id] = { [column.colId]: Number(newValue) };
    }
    setUpdateData(updateData);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've just run into this issue myself too.

It can be replicated fairly easily with this chunk of code:

```js
const [example, setExample] = useState(0);
const CellValueChanged = (params) => {
    console.log(example);
    setExample(example+ 1);
};
```

The expected flow would be:

```
Edit a cell -> 0 (initial value of state) -> edit a cell -> 1 (new state value)
```

However the flow that actually happens is this:

```
Edit a cell -> 0 (initial value of the state) -> edit a cell -> 0 (not grabbing the udpated state value?)
```